# How to pass an object from EJS to Node.js Router - Javascript, EJS, Node.js, MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I am working on looping through records in a MySQL table, displaying them in an EJS file, and when one is clicked on, routing to a page to edit the record. However, I am having trouble passing the single Object back to my routes.js file to route it to the edit page. I have had no problem looping through all the records and printing them, so I know the data is there. Here is the part of the EJS file where I am outputting all of the records for user selection:

```
<body>
<div class="container">

<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

    <h1><span class="fa fa-chess"></span> View Roommate Agreements</h1><br>
    <p align="center">Click on a Roommate Agreement below to view the full response and edit if necessary.</p><br>

    <% for (var i=0; i < Agreements.length; i++) { %>
        <a href="/editAgreement" style="text-decoration: none; color: #333333">
            <div class="well" align="center">

                <h3>Roommate Agreement for Room #<%= Agreements[i].roomNumber%></h3>
                <p><%= Agreements[i].roommate1%></p>
                <p><%= Agreements[i].roommate2%></p>
                <% var Agreement = Agreements[i]%> //THIS is where I'm trying to declare the object
            </div>
        </a>
    <% } %>

    <hr>
    <p align="center">
        <a href="/agreement" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></span> Back</a>
        <a href="/logout" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="fa fa-sign-out-alt"></span> Logout</a>
    </p>

</div>

</div>
</body>
```

And here is the Get function to route the object to the edit page. You can see where I'm trying to log the object to the console to make sure I'm getting the right information, but it's currently printing as "undefined".

```
app.get('/editAgreement', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('editAgreement.ejs', {
        Employee: req.user
    })
    console.log(req.body.Agreement);
})
```

I'm not sure if the problem is how I'm declaring the object variable in EJS or how I'm trying to use it in the Get function, as I am new to Javascript. Any tips or help would be appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: Are you trying to create unique links to each agreement? (Which contain a little extra data like the roommates' names for context?)

Comment: Blake, in order to access the `Agreements` variable in the template, you need to first pass it in from the `render` call, just like how you passed in `Employee`.

Comment: Please post your `get` function in client-side

Comment: @StephenGheysens Once a specific agreement is clicked on, I want it to redirect to a page where the user can edit it. I know I will need to pass it from the `render` call, but I'm still working on getting the data there. That `console.log` function currently prints `undefined` in the console, which it wouldn't if the data was being passed correctly.

Comment: @ShimonBrandsdorfer I'm not quite sure what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: Never mind, I thought you serialize the object on client side, I'm about to post an answer. Hold on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to passe variables to another page using `GET` you have to passe them in the `url`, with that you will expose you data and that's not safe and a lot of work if you have a lot of information to pass,you should passe only the `id` of the agreement to the `get` route, fetch the agreement and then render the view, like :

```
<% for (var i=0; i < Agreements.length; i++) { %>
    <a href="/editAgreement/<%= Agreements[i].id %>" style="text ...
```

and then :

```
app.get('/editAgreement/:id', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    let agreementId = req.params.id;

    let agreement = // go fetch the agreement from the database like you did before with the list of agreements

    res.render('editAgreement.ejs', agreement)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This sounds promising, but I think I am still missing something. Here is what I have for my `get` route now: `app.get('/editAgreement/:agreementID', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  let agreementID = req.params.agreementID;
  var query = ("SELECT * FROM RoommateAgreement WHERE agreementID = ?");
  connection.query(query, agreementID, function(err, rows, fields){
  
   res.render('editAgreement.ejs', {
    Employee: req.user,
    Agreement: rows
   });
  });
 });`

Comment: And here is what I have in EJS: `<% for (var i=0; i < Agreements.length; i++) { %>
  <a href="/editAgreement/<% Agreements[i].agreementID %>" style=` Unfortunately, I am getting a `Cannot GET /editAgreement` error. If these comments are confusing, let me know as the code looks jumbled up. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome :) , your code looks ok, just decide whether to use `var` or `let` ( google that :P )  , i think you just need to restart the node server and refresh the page with `ctrl+F5` , inspect the link to make sure you have `/editAgreement/5` or some id in your `html`

Comment: I don't think the EJS file is building the link correctly. It's not adding the ID to the end.

Comment: oh, sorry, my bad, it should be `<%= Agreement... %>` , i forgot the `=`

Comment: Another quick question while we're at it... When users are redirected to this edit page, I would like for them to see the same exact form that they used to create the agreement with all the values filled in for them to edit. Currently, when I try to fill in the value, it only gives me the first word. It only does this in form sections, not other parts of the page, for example the title. This is what I have written `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="roommate1" value=<%= Agreement[0].roommate1%>>` and if the value is "Blake Lewis" it's only giving me "Blake". Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the Object sent along with your `GET` request, you need to send them along, and it doesn't seem from your code that you are doing it.

The quickest solution would be to use the `querystring` module. By requirting it on the top of your code, and then use it to send the agreement Object, as follows:

```
<% 

 const querystring = require('querystring');
 for (var i=0; i < Agreements.length; i++) { 
       var Agreement = Agreements[i]
 %>
        <a href="/editAgreement/?<%= querystring.stringify(Agreement) %>" style="text-decoration: none; color: #333333">
            <div class="well" align="center">

                <h3>Roommate Agreement for Room #<%= Agreement.roomNumber%></h3>
                <p><%= Agreement.roommate1%></p>
                <p><%= Agreement.roommate2%></p>
            </div>
        </a>
    <% } %>
```